# On laravel 7.6.2 'WhereBetween' not working with the requested numbers

Tags: php, laravel

WhereBetween query not working with the min and max numbers which passed from price filter.Query return empty array. I check this query with other numbers like min~ 1 and max~200 it is working.
Controller:

```
$products = Product::whereBetween('pr_last_price',[$request->minamount,$request->maxamount])->get();
dd($products);
```

But like that query works correctly

```
$products = Product::whereBetween('pr_last_price',[1,200])->get();
dd($products);
```

I controlled my numbers which came from form as request everything is ok.

Comment: Does `$products = Product::whereBetween('pr_last_price',[intval($request->minamount), intval($request->maxamount)])->get();`  work?

Comment: If the second works and the first has issues, the problem is with `$request->minamount` - are you sure you've referenced that variable correctly?

Comment: @apokryfos yes intval solved my problem thank you